# Steam Web API via Node.js on my shared hosting

Tags: node.js, steam-web-api

Basically, what I'm trying to do is have the Steam Web API running via Node.js on my shared hosting so I can display Steam user profile information on my site. Unfortunately, I'm having a lot of trouble getting it working. I've been following [this guide](https://codepen.io/johnchristopherjones/post/how-do-i-use-the-steam-api-in-my-web-app).

[This](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10047/2182/how-to-work-with-nodejs-app) is what I followed to get NodeJS running.

I have it set up like so:

```
Node.js version - 9.11.2
Application mode - Production
Application root - /home/<name>/nodejs/steamapi-server
Application URL - <mysite.com>/steamapi-server
Application startup file - server.js
```

[My server.js file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/johnchristopherjones/c6c8928d2ffa5ccbda6a/raw/7df75f5de7ef766c70ee09d4129826e3245d3b83/server.js) (minus my API key).

[My package.json file](https://pastebin.com/RxNXzi8r).

All dependencies are installed and the script is running.
However, when I go to /steamapi-server all I get is: *Cannot GET /steamapi-server/* whereas I would normally be seeing "Hello, World!".
I tested this all locally beforehand and it was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to change app.get('/' to app.get('/steamapi-server'

Now it's working.